# Difference between TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener and TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout within a viewpager and would like to listen for tab changes. Which listener should I use? The first seems to work fine but then what is the purpose of the second one?

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) say that the second listener provides callbacks to the viewpager but it doesn't make it clear what that means/why it's necessary or a good idea.

Comment: `OnTabSelectedListener` is an interface. `ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener` is an implementation of that interface that simply sets the `ViewPager`'s current page in `onTabSelected()`. It's really just a convenience class. You could easily implement it yourself. If your `TabLayout` is inside the `ViewPager`, then it's already being setup with the `ViewPager`, and a `ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener` is set internally. If you want to listen to tab changes externally as well, add your own `OnTabSelectedListener`. You don't really need to worry about `ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener`.

Answer (score 0):

A `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` class which contains the necessary calls back to the provided `ViewPager` so that the tab position is kept in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` you need to call viewpager to change the page, but in `TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener` you can link the TabLayout and the ViewPager with `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(ViewPager)`, `tabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener` will pass you the viewpager as parameter each time the user change of tab.

I recommend you use the one with which you feel more comfortable